# Make text bottom aligned even during overflow in Android

Tags: android, layout, textview, alignment

I am using `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in my text view which is in RelativeLayout. It works well - aligns the text at the bottom. However, when the text is larger then the container, it overflows and starts being aligned at the top. I want to keep text being aligned at the bottom all the time. How to accomplish that? Simply - I want to achieve normal text-chat behaviour without need to scroll.

No overflow - it is ok:

[image: 1]

Overflow - can't see bottom lines, line 1 is always first at top:

[image: 2]

What I want to achieve:

[image: 2]

Comment: What if you call `invalidate()` on your TextView?

Comment: Nope, that's not the thing. Even long text defined in `android:text` behaves this wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things you could try to fix this problem:

1) You could put `android:singleLine="true"` in the layout of the textview so it does not become bigger than its container.

2) Try putting `android:gravity="bottom|left"` in the textview's layout and see if that will align the textview to the bottom left.

3) Make the layout like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >    
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>    
    </RelativeLayout>    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

Another solution is to make the textview scrollable. Just set the `android:maxLines` and `android:scrollbars = "vertical"`. Then add `TextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())` in your java code and your textview will be scrollable.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work. I used your layout and get what you can see in the attached screenshots.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, but you could try checking if the size of the textview is greater than the size of the screen. If so, then take the difference between the the textview size and the screen size and set that value as the marginTop of the textview.

Comment: I don't want it to be scrollable! :)

Comment: Did you try the solution I gave in the comment before the one that said: "check my update".

Comment: The thing with the negative margin is a kind of brute-force, but it works. It seems it has to stay that way. Thanks for the idea!